# jquery resizable 1px mismatch error

Tags: javascript, jquery, resizable

I am trying to use jquery resizable handlers with absolute position square  divs

but when I click the "north" and "west" button(only this two direction) and drag just a little for resizing, the box itself became smaller by 1 or 2px

in north handler case, like (top:100px,height:100px => top:99px,height:99px)

what did I do wrong??

```
element.resizable({
    minWidth: 1,
    minHeight: 1,
    handles:{
        'n': '.ui-resizable-n',
        'w': '.ui-resizable-w',
        'e': '.ui-resizable-e',
        's': '.ui-resizable-s'
    }
})
```

Here's [a demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/5ynavg9x/2/)!

when I drag "keeper" item to "screen" and move north resize handler little, the square makes problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change `box-sizing: border-box;` to `box-sizing: content-box;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/6h02cmvf/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container > .ui-element-libraries-container > .ui-element-container').draggable({
   opacity: 0.5,
   helper: "clone",
   appendTo: '#full',
   cursor: "move",
   revert: true
  })

  $('#screen').droppable({
   drop: (event,ui)=>{
    let layoutOffset=$('#screen').offset()
    let element=ui.helper.clone().css({
     'position': 'absolute',
     'opacity': 1,
     'left': (ui.position.left-layoutOffset.left)+'px',
     'top': (ui.position.top-layoutOffset.top)+'px',
    })
    element.toggleClass('ui-element-container ui-element')
    element.empty()
    element.append("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n'></div>")
    element.append("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s'></div>")
    element.append("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e'></div>")
    element.append("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w'></div>")
    element.appendTo('#screen')
    element.resizable({
     minWidth: 1,
     minHeight: 1,
     handles:{
      'n': '.ui-resizable-n',
      'w': '.ui-resizable-w',
      'e': '.ui-resizable-e',
      's': '.ui-resizable-s'
     }
    })
    ui.helper.remove()
   }
  })
 })
```

```css
.pane{
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#container{
  margin: 0px;
  left: 300px;
  right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}
#screen{
  margin: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}
.ui-element-libraries-container{
  width:100%;
}
.ui-element-container{
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 33.3%;
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 90px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  float:left;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: move;    
}
.ui-element{
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  float:left;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: move; 
}
.ui-resizable-handle{
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}
.ui-resizable-n{
  top: -4px;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  margin-left: -4px;
  cursor: ns-resize;  
}
.ui-resizable-s{
  top: auto;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  margin-left: -4px;
  cursor: ns-resize;  
}
.ui-resizable-e{
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-w{
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: -4px;
  right: auto;
  margin-top: -4px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="full">
  <div id="screen" class="pane">
    screen
  </div>
  <div id="container" class="pane">
    keeper
    <div class="ui-element-libraries-container">
      <div class="ui-element-container">
        <div>
          b
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```